# Why request layout for recycler item stops layout operations?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

### scenario:

When my ViewPager get clicked on a side the next/previous video is animated into the screen.
example:
video 01 -> video 02 (watch from Right To Left)
 [image: step 3] [image: 2] [image: step 1]

---

### The problem:

after clicking for jumping into the next video, the transition is stuck in the middle:
[image: stuck]

the UI is still responding except the ViewPager.
the ViewPager is stuck only for a few secs. 
this problem usually happens for the first click.

---

### Archtecture and logic

ConstraintLayout which includes:
- viewpager
on top of the ViewPager:
- toolbar
- RecyclerView (blue line and text below)

while the viewpager is scrolled due to a click i use the function:

```
onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int)
```

by using this data i'm changing the recycler item bounds (layoutParams)

---

### What i've found out:

when not changing the recycler itemView layoutParams **or**
when setting the recycler itemView as MATCH_PARENT (for test only, i must use WARP_CONTENT) and do change the layoutParams, the viewPager works just fine.

I already tried to update the **recycler item** once in 80ms (really slow) and the UI still freeze.
so i don't understand:
- why is it happening
- why when updating recycler item the viewpager is getting stuck for few secs - there is no connection between the to views.

Comment: Could you attach your layout and some code? And also how the scroll/swipe is invoked. A gif would also be helpful to understand the issue better

Comment: 2 Directions I would look into:
1. Since it happens only the first time, it might be related to the way ViewPager and the adapter are instantiated. Since you didn't post code, I can suggest you call a dummy call on the ViewPager for start, maybe setCurrentItem(0, true) to see if that solves it.
2. I would check if the call to the RecyclerView causes the ViewPager to re-render for some reason, holding it stuck mid-animation. Create your own MyViewPager that extends ViewPager and put logs in all of the onDraw, onMeasure, onLayout methods to see if any of them gets called after the RCV change

Comment: Also, why do you need a RecyclerView at the top? Wouldn't a LinearLayout do? If so, I think the behavior you are looking for is easily achieved with a LinearLayout